# command line returning new line immediately

Tags: java, command-line, user-input

I'm writing a command line Java applicaton. I have a class that handles terminal input/output. I am wanting to ask a simple yes/no (y/n) question.
This is my code:

```
public boolean yn(String prompt) {
    // ask a yes/no question
    out(prompt);
    try {
        while(true) {
            char result = (char) br.read();
            out("\n");
            if( ( (Character) Character.toLowerCase(result) ).toString().equals("y") ) {
                return true;
            } else if( ( (Character) Character.toLowerCase(result) ).toString().equals("n") ) {
                return false;
            }
            // not y or n
            out(Messages.informYN);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

*br* is a BufferedReader set up as

```
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

*out* simply outputs text

```
System.out.print(text);
```

**The issue is br.read() immediately returns a new line the first time, when no input has been given.**

I'm fairly new to Java, so go easy on me please.

Comment: Have you tried using readln: `char result = br.readLine().charAt(0);`

Comment: Also, can you show code where you are calling this method?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels the readln code throws an index out of range exception. The line that calls it is simply `boolean cont = terminal.yn(Messages.noMatchConfirmation);`

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem. This works fine for me : `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
char result = (char) br.read();
System.out.println(result);`

Comment: Maybe the issue lies deeper in the code, I will investigate now

Comment: Yep, I'll bet the problem is in how you're trying to use this method.

Answer (score 0):

This method reads from console until [Enter] is pressed:

```
    public final String ConsoleReadln(String promptStr) {
    StringBuffer retSb = new StringBuffer();

    try {
        System.out.print(promptStr);
        byte[] buf = new byte[1];
        System.in.skip(System.in.available());
        int i = 0;
        char c = 0;
        do {
            if ( System.in.read(buf,0,1) > 0 ) {
                i = (int) buf[0]; if (i<0) i += 0x100; c = (char) i;
                if ((c != '\n') && (c != '\r')) retSb.append(c);
            }
        }
        while ((c != '\n') && (c != '\r')) ;
    } // try
    catch (Exception ex)  {
    }
    return retSb.toString();
}
```